.po files not found when importing the file under Drupal locale
I have ... /admin/config/regional/translate/import
I can locate the po-file on my PC under H:\wamp\www\locale\fr_BE\LC_MESSAGES and select the languauge fr_BE.
The po. and mo-file have been prepared wit Poedit.
But when I start "Import" I get the messages: "No file selected"  with the comment "A gettext Portable Object (.po)-file" and  further "Source file not selected".
What did I wrong?
Thanks
Walter
What did I wrong?
Thanks
Walter

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

When I am trying to import a po file, I get the message that the file was not selected. What do I have to do get the file processed although I have selected the file on the form?

When I look at locale.admin.inc I find this:

See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18807069/drupal-7-file-save-upload-returning-false  Why do I get this for a /locale/fr_BE/LC_MESSAGESmessage.po file??

Problem solved. This is not a Drupal problem. Ihttps://www.drupal.org/forum/support/translations/2009-01-26/cannot-import-po-files-for-translation
